# ckeditor - cannot change toolbar using JS

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, toolbar

Can someone explain why this isn't changing the toolbar?

I have used the sample code and followed the example that is provided within the downloadable archive but still have not had any joy - any ideas.

I have added the code to pastebin here :-
http://pastebin.com/YXiNjh7A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to CKEDITOR.replace at line 6 is failing because the textarea doesn't exist yet, and then it's being automatically being replaced (with the default settings) because it has the class "ckeditor"

And please, use a Doctype, we're not in 1995.